# How to use methods define in http://www.rubydoc.info/ site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rdoc

I have open rails console and want to use pluralize method but i am getting error as `NoMethodError: undefined method`pluralize' for main:Object`

pluralize(1, 'person')

i can see the documentation for this method here http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper#pluralize-instance_method but i don't know how to use this documentation. i have tried below code but it didn't work

```
ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.new.puralize(1, 'person')
ActionView::Helpers.new.pluralize(1 , 'person')
```

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Not:

```
ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.new.puralize(1, 'person')

or

ActionView::Helpers.new.pluralize(1 , 'person')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling using `new`:

```
ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.new.puralize(1, 'person')
ActionView::Helpers.new.pluralize(1 , 'person')
```

You should call it using include `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`. Like below.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

pluralize(1, 'person')
# => 1 person

pluralize(2, 'person')
# => 2 people

pluralize(3, 'person', 'users')
# => 3 users

pluralize(0, 'person')
# => 0 people
```

Comment: Ok. so that means if there is module in rubydocinfo then we have to include it and if there is class in rubydocinfo then we have to instantiate  and use it .. right??

Comment: @Lokesh Harjani, I always call using `include` and/or `require`. If my answer helped you, please accept the answer. Thanks!